# Как изменить hostname в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Как изменить hostname в Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hostname
```

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то меняется редактированием данного файла.

Comment: нашел ответ:
нужно поправить 2 файла:
/etc/hostname
/etc/hosts